# Return different DataMembers from different endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to return different DataMembers of a class depending on the endpoint it is returned from?

From one endpoint I only want to return just some basic DataMembers of a class, but from another endpoint I want to return more detailed members of the same class.

My thought is that I can have a basic class and derive another class which has more detailed information and return these from the different endpoints, but I was also wondering if there is another way this could be achieved?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Could you give an example of a service interface and the objects that you want to send?

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion is perfectly reasonable. These classes are DTO's anyway (presumably) and their whole point is to decouple your business models from your message models. If you have two message models, having one derive (or contain) the other is fine.

Consider, what would an alternative model look like? A single type with complicated annotations denoting which service those Data Members belong to? This would get unwieldy quickly, and that's not even considering how your business objects will map to this model (ie will the mapping need to know which endpoint is being called? That's very ugly).

So just:

```
public class EntityBase
{
    // basic details here
}

public class EntityDetails: EntityBase
{
    // more complex details initialised here
}
```

Then your endpoints can be strongly typed against these, you can sharing mapping logic, and you achieve what you want.